# Python tool for performance profiling

Tags: java, python, performance, jprofiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you profile a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

What visual tools do you know, something similar to JProfiler for Java, to analyze performance of Python applications?

Comment: exact duplicate of _what_, exactly?

Comment: Above my question I see a section named Possible Duplicate(How can you profile a Python script? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cProfile` or `profile` to profile your code.

And if you need memory profiling, you can use `guppy`.